# Set the heap start address in C program?

Tags: c, gcc, elf, heap-memory

Is there a way to set the heap start address in GCC compiled C program in linux? In x86_64 system,my test program sets the heap address to 4 byte referenced address ( less than FFFFFFFF). I want to set this to 8 byte referenced address for some testing ( > FFFFFFFF). Does GCC provide any way to set the heap start address?

Comment: Please define what "heap start address" is to you. Most `malloc`-s are using `mmap` (and that is subject to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)...)

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you care?

Comment: I am debugging a crash which seems to be happening when heap is more than 4 bytes, I am guessing this could be happening  due to some pointer to integer assignment. But my test program always have heap in 4 bytes addressable space.

Comment: Can this not be done with the linker?

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this a bit indirectly using `sbrk()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  sbrk(0xFFFFFFFF);
  printf("%p\n", malloc(1));
  return 0;
}
```

This works by "allocating" 0xFFFFFFFF bytes at the very start, so that the next thing `malloc()` can allocate is a higher address.

Comment: Might not always work, since most `malloc`-s are using more and more `mmap`. Actually, `sbrk` or even heap start is not much used today (in particular because it is not multithread friendly)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: using `sbrk()` will effectively reserve all the virtual addresses from somewhere a bit above zero to over 0xFFFFFFFF.  So mmap() or not, malloc() will have no choice but to return high addresses as the OP requested.  Do you have a counter-example?  I tried changing the malloc() size in my code above to be a few megabytes which made it use mmap(), but the address was even higher then, never below 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @John Zwinck Well, it will not reserve from address 0, it will reserve from wherever the current data segment starts - there's can be a  lot of stuff mapped at lower addresses. Theoretically a malloc implementation could find a hole in the mappings somewhere there to allocate from.

Comment: @nos: I'm not really clear on how that would happen: malloc() will call sbrk() and that can only grow the segment, not "find holes in the mappings."  I'm ready to believe you're right, that it could technically happen that way, I just don't see how...unless mmap() gives low addresses, which on 64-bit systems I've seen doesn't really seem to happen.  Anyway, it seems this solution is good enough for the OP, but nice to understand the finer points.